# backButtonItem stuck with default behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've tried a few different tweaks to get my backBarButtonItem to run different methods, but no matter what, it only executes the default behavior of backing up a page, and seemingly ignores whatever I set as its target & action.

```
   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
   [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                      target:self
                                      action:@selector(foo)] autorelease];
```

In keeping with other Q&A sessions here on StackOverflow, I've set the backBarButtonItem in the page before the one that uses it. Counterintuitive, but that part works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
   [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                      target:self
                                      action:@selector(foo)] autorelease];
```

Use left bar button item instead.

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly, when handled that way, the button needs to be set in the view itself, not the one before.